# Binding to model inside model inside viewmodel not binding both ways Xamarin forms firebase

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

so iv'e been scratching my head at this for a while now. Basically I am retrieving data from firebase cloud firestore and mapping that data to a model. The structure is business_availability(collection) > base_opening_times (document) which contains 7 map fields (one for each day of the week). That data gets retrieved and mapped to a model correctly. The Model contains 7 days of which each day is itself a model called DayInWeek, DayInWeek contains three fields that are mapped to when the data is retrieved. So far so good (sorry this is awfully complicated). Well the issue is when I bind to a field in day in week, I can read it's value but I cannot update it. This is important because the user might need to update a businessOpeningTimes. The user should be able to save those changes and the new values get written to the database. It all works on the back end with hard coded values etc. The issue is the Binding. Below I have included my code. I have trie Binding Mode(s) (all of them). I have tried making another BusinessOpeningTimesModel called NewBusinessOpeningTimes. I tried binding to that instead and just writing the values to the db from that. Again it doesn't update after the user changes a value (before writing - just for the binding). This is probably something someone has come across before and any advice would be greatly appreciated (As always).

Here is the BusinessOpeningTimesModel:

```
public class BusinessManagementOpeningTimeModel
{
    [Id]
    public string BusinessBaseOpeningTimesId {get; set;}

    [MapTo("monday")]
    public DayInWeek Monday { get; set; }

    [MapTo("tuesday")]
    public DayInWeek Tuesday { get; set; }

    [MapTo("wednesday")]
    public DayInWeek Wednesday { get; set; }

    [MapTo("thursday")]
    public DayInWeek Thursday { get; set; }

    [MapTo("friday")]
    public DayInWeek Friday { get; set; }

    [MapTo("saturday")]
    public DayInWeek Saturday { get; set; }

    [MapTo("sunday")]
    public DayInWeek Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the DayInWeekModel:

```
public class DayInWeek
{

    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }

    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
private BusinessManagementOpeningTimeModel _openingTimes;
    public BusinessManagementOpeningTimeModel OpeningTimes
    {
        get
        {
            
            return _openingTimes;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_openingTimes != value)
            {
                _openingTimes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the XAML (there is one of these for each day in the week):

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                            <Label Text="MON" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="0,0,50,0"/>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">


                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusinessOpeningTimesVisible}">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding OpeningTimes.Monday.StartTime}"/>
                                        <Label Text=" - "/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding OpeningTimes.Monday.EndTime}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>



                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding IsOpeningTimesEditable}">

                                        <Entry Style="{StaticResource TimeEntryStyle}"
                                               Text="{Binding OpeningTimes.Monday.StartTime}"/>
                                       
                                        <Label Text=" - "/>

                                        <Entry Style="{StaticResource TimeEntryStyle}"
                                               Text="{Binding OpeningTimes.Monday.EndTime}"/>

                                    </StackLayout>

                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: becuase neither `BusinessManagementOpeningTimeModel` nor `DayInWeek` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "doesn't update".  The UI doesn't update?  The model?  The db?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the setter for `EndTime` to see if it is being called when you update the UI?  If it's just that the UI is not updating, that is likely due to INPC like @Selvin points out

Comment: so obviously if you change `OpeningTimes` to new instance then it will be changed in view ... but if you change `OpeningTimes.Monday` it will not ... BTW there are some code gennerators for autoimplementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (like Fody.PropertyChanged )

Comment: ahh, I see. Can I implement INotifyPropertyChanged inside a model? I'll look into the Fody.PropertyChanged now. So basically the UI gets changed by the user, that then doesn't update say Monday.StartTime. So when I try to write that model to the DB it has the exact same values as it did when it read them in from the DB. Sorry, it's rather difficult to explain. So should I implement INotifyPropertyChanged inside the DayInWeek model as well as the BusinessOpeningTimes model?

Comment: @Jason I have changed the DayInWeek model to ' private bool _isOpen;
        public bool IsOpen
        {
            get
            {
                return _isOpen;
            }

            set
            {
                _isOpen = value;
            }
        }' etc it does hit the breakpoint on the set. I clearly need to implement the above that Selvin mentioned. Only problem is I'm not sure how to do that inside a model that's inside a model that's inside a viewmodel. Please advise guys. Also thank you for the help here! You really are heroes!

Comment: @Selvin I forgot to tag you back in the comment above the last.

Comment: don't worry about the nesting.  Just implement INPC on the class that contains the property you care about.  And as @Selvin mentioned Fody will make your life a lot easier when doing this

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the swift response I really appreciate it. I'll try it using Fody, but that'll mean I need to change all of my other properties to auto-properties right?

Comment: no, if you aren't using INPC currently then it really won't matter

Comment: @Jason I am using it in all of my ViewModels just not the models. So can I just change all my VM's to autoProperty's now?

Comment: I would probably implement INPC on this model first to see if it fixes your current problem.  Then I'd worry about whether or not you want to refactor your project to use Fody

Comment: @Jason I see, I've added Fody and I'm testing it now, so hopefully this solves the issue. I'll update shortly :). Thanks again guys

Comment: @Jason that worked a treat. Only trouble is it doesn't work with TimePicker but I'll get by on strings (unless either of you guys know a way around this?). Also thank you Selvin too for your advice